# Change default table "width" and "style" properties in JCE Editor

Tags: joomla-2.5, jce

When I copy an existing `table` (4 columns, 5 rows) in the JCE Editor (WYSIWYG view) and then paste. The `width` and `style` properties in the *pasted* `table` are "defaulted" and I need them to remain *empty*, as they are in the table I copied.

Is there any way to configure this?

The table `width` attribute appears to be defaulting to the current width of the editor (`1146px` in my case) and the `style` attribute is defaulting to `font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif; width: 1146px;` - which crucially contains the `width` property as well! This then overrides the `class` that is applied to the `table`.

I've checked the configuration options for the JCE Editor, but I cannot find any settings for these two properties. Where is it getting these values from?

Incidentally, these properties are only defaulted when I copy and **paste** the table. If I create a new table then these properties do not default and remain empty.

JCE Editor 2.5.2 (current)

Comment: Are you using the latest version of JCE Editor (2.5.2)? And are you pasting your table code into the **Source Code** section? I have just tried installing a fresh copy of JCE Editor, pasting your cod, and it works fine.

Comment: @Lodder Yes, I'm using JCE Editor 2.5.2. As stated, I'm using the WYSIWYG view (this is a repeated action that needs to be performed by a non-technical end user). Yes, if I use the Source Code view I can paste whatever I like and nothing gets defaulted or changed.

Comment: When I have to paste complicated html, I use the source editor.

Comment: It seems the width of the table is defaulting to the width of the editor "container" at the time the table is copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OMG! The JCE Editor was just being annoyingly clever!

The `table` in question has a particular class applied to it. This class is copied across no problem, however, in my `editor.css` this class is defined as having `width:100%`. When *pasting* the table with this class already applied, it seems it was *calculating* the width as 100% the width of the editor viewport (1146px as stated above)!! Reducing this to `width:50%` resulted in a width half that.

It seems that for any percentage width, the editor was calculating the corresponding `px` width! If I set a fixed width in the CSS eg. `width:960px` then the editor did not default anything.

My workaround is to change `width:100%` in editor.css to `min-width:100%` - the styles still work as intended and the editor does not try to default the width!

This would seem to be very "clever", however, I can't for the life of me think why anyone would want this?